# Convert select to vue-select with dynamic data

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-select

(Laravel)I have:

> import vSelect from 'vue-select'
>
> Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);

```
  <select v-model="metaSeleccionada" class="form-control" style="height: 35.9px;" placeholder="Enter last name" id="selectPersona">
                              <option value="" disabled hidden>Seleccione la meta</option>
                              <option v-for="meta in metas" v-bind:value="meta.META_intId">
                                @{{ meta.META_varSubMeta }}: 
                                @{{ meta.META_varDenominacion }}
                              </option>
  </select>
```

I want to convert it to vue-select, I tried that in my blade:

```
  <v-select :options="metas" label="META_intId">
                          <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                              @{{ option.META_varSubMeta }} : @{{ option.META_varDenominacion}}
                          </template>
   </v-select>
```

Comment: what is v-select?You are using vuetify framework?

Comment: i'm using Laravel and vue js [import vSelect from 'vue-select'

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);] @roliroli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone has the same problem, it was my solution:

```
<v-select  
                        label="META_varDenominacion" 
                        :options="metas"
                        v-model="metaSeleccionada"
                        placeholder="Seleccione una Meta"
                      >  
                         <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                            {{ option.META_varSubMeta }}: 
                            {{ option.META_varDenominacion }}
                         </template>
  </v-select>
```

the problem was that I was calling methods of v-select in the view, when I changed everything to a component of vuejs it works perfectly.
Now i have:

> import Vue from 'vue'
>   import vSelect from 'vue-select'
>   Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);

and

> Vue.component('contratos-component',
>   require('./components/ContratoComponent.vue'));

This is where i'm calling v-select